# Log4j2 JDBCAppender with Weblogic connection pool for oracle DB

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, oracle12c, log4j2, weblogic12c

We have a spring mvc web app deployed on weblogic 12c connecting to Oracle DB 12c via weblogic connection pool. It uses log4j2 (2.9.1) JDBC appender to log to DB. Below is the appender configuration

```
<JDBC name="app-api-db" tableName="API_AUDIT_LOG">
<DataSource jndiName="appdb"></DataSource>
<Column>....</Column> *//isClob="true" for 2 columns isEventTimestamp="true" for 1 column*
</JDBC>
```

Weblogic Datasource has below configurations -

```
Initial Capacity 20
Max Capacity 850
Does not support global transactions
```

This same datasource is also being used by the application i.e. there is no separate datasource for log4j2 jdbc appender.

This set up has been working fine for sometime now but since last year, when the volume of incoming requests increased substantially, it is being observed that the oracle TEMP tablespace is
increasing gradually till it is completely exhausted. Only an application restart solves the issue. We tried increasing the temp space but that also does not solve the issue.

It seems majority of the SQLs using the TEMP space are the ones issued by log4j async jdbc db appender. We have turned it off in production since a month now and it seems TEMP space usage is much lesser now.

Any pointers to why this may be happening?

Below is the SQL we are using to check TEMP space usage. Seems most of the session ids being reported are in INACTIVE status but still TEMP space is not being released. Could it be related to connection pool settings?

```
SELECT b.tablespace,
sum(ROUND(((b.blocks*p.value)/1024/1024),2)) AS temp_size_MB,
a.inst_id as Instance,
a.sid||','||a.serial# sid_serial#,
NVL(a.username, '(oracle)') AS username,
substr(a.program,1,30) program,
substr(a.machine,1,15) machine,
a.sql_id
FROM   gv$session a,
gv$sort_usage b,
gv$parameter p
WHERE  p.name  = 'db_block_size'
AND    a.saddr = b.session_addr
AND    a.inst_id=b.inst_id
AND    a.inst_id=p.inst_id
group by b.tablespace, a.username, a.inst_id, a.sid, a.serial#, a.program, a.sql_id, a.machine
order by a.inst_id, temp_size_MB, a.username, a.program, a.machine;
```

Comment: You should identify the queries that allocate the TEMP tablespace. The only expeced statements for a DB logging appender are `insert .. value` that *does not* use `TEMP`

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too since I think temp space is mainly used for sorting. If I take the "sid" from above SQL and search in v$session, I can see an SQL id under PREV_SQL_ID column. If I search v$sql using this SQL ID, I do see the INSERT sql issued by  log4j2 jdbc appender. Is PREV_SQL_ID column in v$session recording the last SQL issued by that particular session?

Comment: Yep, if the `SQL_ID` is null.

Comment: Thanks for the responses @MarmiteBomber. If an INSERT sql is not supposed to use TEMP space, then why is this logging appender insert showing up in v$sort_usage? Is it like some other SQL may have caused the allocation of TEMP space but then the same session also latter executed the INSERT? If yes, how to debug this as for the session I only see PREV_SQL_ID. Also most sessions showing up in result set of above SQL are in INACTIVE status. Also the fact that once we disabled this appender, temp space usage seems to be stable with no spikes.